# QSqlQueryModel complains that my database is not open

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, qt, qtsql

I am trying to use `QSqlQueryModel` in order to retrieve some values from my database like such:

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL", "test1");
 db.setHostName(Vars::strDbHost);
 db.setDatabaseName(Vars::strDbName);
 db.setPort(Vars::strDbPort);
 db.setUserName(Vars::strDbUsername);
 db.setPassword(Vars::strDbPassword);

 db.open()

 QSqlQueryModel model;
 model.setQuery(QString("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=%2").arg(Vars::strUserLogin));
```

But I keep getting a `QSqlQuery::exec: database not open` error.

Why is this, and how can I correctly use `QSqlQueryModel` to retrieve the values I want?

Comment: `if (!db.open()) qDebug() << db.lastError().text();`. Also, where did you set your db to a model?

Comment: I did not add it in the question but I did made sure that the database is open and returns no errors. I actually tried the same thing but with a query, and it went fine.

Comment: You are calling the wrong version of `setQuery`. This only works with db which have the default name. In your case, you need to call `void setQuery(const QString &query, const QSqlDatabase &db)`

Comment: Nowhere! this is my first try and I sort of trying to figure it out from the docs.

Comment: Amartel is right. This is a common mistake.

Comment: I think it is ok now. Can you please make your last comment into an answer.

Comment: @OnWhenReady it just that I could not find a complete example of using it, so I wanted to make sure I know what I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the wrong version of `setQuery`. This only works with db which have the default name. In your case, you need to call `void QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(const QString &query, const QSqlDatabase &db)`:

```
model.setQuery(QString("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=%2").arg(Vars::strUserLogin)
               , db);
```